# SharePoint Full Permissions

Tags: permissions, site

I have give someone full permissions to my SharePoint site but they are unable to add a new user. The NEW button is not available, has anyone come across this before?

Comment: Is this a subsite, with a parent site where the user doesn't have full control?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to add a user into a SharePoint group and they can't see the New button. To fix this, the Group Owner or Site Collection Administrator needs to go to the group and click Settings -> Group Settings.

From here, check the Owner field. You can change this field to be the name of the person who needs to add members to this group. Alternatively, you can change the group settings so that anyone in the group can edit the membership of the group (you can do this below the Owner field).